# The argument type 'Future<Uint8List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'. While attempting to load image from byte in Flutter

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

I'm trying to load an image from byte (stored in BLOB column) which I retrieved from MySQL database, so what I did in order to do that first I connect to the database and return the byte value:

```
class MySqlModel {
  Future<Uint8List> connectionFunc(String _Username, String _FileName) async {
    final conn = await MySQLConnection.createConnection(
      host: "",
      port: 0000,
      userName: "",
      password: "-0",
      databaseName: "", 
    );

    await conn.connect();
    var _SelectFileByte = await conn.execute("SELECT FILE_BYTE FROM image_tab WHERE USERNAME = :username AND FILEANME = :filename",
    {
      "username": _Username,
      "filename": _FileName 
    });
    var _getByteValue;
    for(var Res in _SelectFileByte.rows) {
      _getByteValue = await Res.assoc()['FILE_BYTE'];
    }
    return await _getByteValue;
  }
}
```

Now load the image:

```
body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height:300,
              width:400,
              child: Image.memory(MySqlModel().connectionFunc("henrydaniel","dad1.png")),
            )
          ]
        )
      ),

`
```

But I got an error saying: `The argument type 'Future<Uint8List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.`

So I tried to fix it by changing `Future<Uint8List> connectionFunc()` to `Uint8List connectionFunc()` but this will cause a problem like:

> Functions marked 'async' must have a return type assignable to 'Future'.
> Try fixing the return type of the function, or removing the modifier 'async' from the function body.

because `Future` is required to make a connection to MySQL database, so my question is how do I make it possible to return a proper Uint8List byte value in my case?

This is the byte data that was inserted:

```
    Uint8List _getFileValues = File(_FilePathVal).readAsBytesSync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `connectionFunc` is async method, you need to change return dataType as Future.

```dart
 Future<Uint8List> connectionFunc(
```

Now to read future on widget, it is better to use FutureBuilder.

```dart
late final future = MySqlModel().connectionFunc("henrydaniel", "dad1.png", "");
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 300,
          width: 400,
          child: FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.data != null)
                  return Image.memory(snapshot.data!);
                return Text("got null");
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        )
      ]));
}
```

Find more about [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Sir I've added extra line `future: future` under the `FutureBuilder<Uint8List>` but now when I tried to load the image it just stuck on circular loading??

Comment: Apparently I got an error saying: `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Uint8List>` how do I fix this?

Comment: `_getByteValue` is string ?

Comment: I check the `_getByteValue` variable type by executing `_getByteValue.runtimeType` and it returns string! I don't know why??..

Comment: Ok I converted the `_getByteValue` to Uint8List now on the program it says `Exception: Invalid image data`.

Comment: Ok nevermind I've successfully loaded the image by encoding and decoding, thank you so much yeasin!